# Define a background image and an icon in C# with Avalonia

Tags: c#, avaloniaui, avalonia

EDIT : My program doesn't start after adding the Background, and an icon to the program I added:
Icon="/assets/icon.ico"
Background="/assets/background.svg">
I checked if I had made a mistake but in my code everything is OK finally according to the IDE and according to me the beginner

Class MainWindow.xaml.cs :

```
    using Avalonia.Controls;
    using Avalonia.Interactivity;
    
    namespace AvaloApp;
    
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    
    
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    
        private void startButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                Button start = new Button();
            }
    
        private void stopButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                Button stop = new Button();
            }
    
        private void hotkeyButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                Button hotkey = new Button();
            }
    
    
    
        }


Class MainWindow.xaml : 
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
        x:Class="AvaloApp.MainWindow"
        Title="AvaloApp"
        Icon="/assets/icon.ico"
         Background="/assets/background.svg">
      

        <Grid>
                
                <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="start" Content="Start" Click="startButton" Margin="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Height="50"/>
                <Button Grid.Column="2"  Grid.Row="0" x:Name="stop" Content="Stop" Click="stopButton" Margin="280,5,5,5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Height="50"/>
                <Button Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="hotkey" Content="Hotkey" Click="hotkeyButton" Margin="5,140,5,5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200" Height="50"/>

        </Grid>

</Window>
```

I tried to debug the program, it says that it does not find the icon, except that it is placed here in the project structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBUdj.png (in the assets folder) and in my code I have specified the location

Even removing the / before assets still doesn't find the file, and surely prevents the project from running properly
The result is the same when I put the images like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExntE.png

Answer (score 0):

Avalonia 0.10 doesn't support svg natively - use a png instead.

Ensure the images in the assets folder have a Build Action of "AvaloniaResource".

The Avalonia [Window](https://reference.avaloniaui.net/api/Avalonia.Controls/Window/#Properties) Background property requires an IBrush that you can add with a child tag:

```csharp
<Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush Source="/assets/test.png" />
</Window.Background>
```